# CSS I would like the hover effect to activate only when i mouseover the image in a column of a row

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, jsx

My hover effect works but the only problem is that if my mouse is over any part of the column in a row it will activate it. How do i get it to only have the effect when I hover the image instead.

Here is my JSX code:

```
      <div className="container App">
    <Header />
    <div className="caption-style-1 row">
      <div className="hover-img col-md-6 col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div id="photography">
          <img
            src={require("../img/chaps_1x.jpg")}
            className="image"
          />
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="text">Photography</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4>CONTACT</h4>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS code: Here I have everything in place but the only problem i can't figure out is how to not let the hover be affected by the remaining space in my column. If I inspect my #photography it is the whole column when i only want to highlight the image. It won't hover if i change the

```
.image {
width: 50%;
height: auto;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height: auto;
width: 50%;
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.hover-img:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.text{
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nopadding{
padding:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN's Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

> ```
> /* Paragraphs that come immediately after any image */
> img + p {
>   font-style: bold;
> }
> ```

```css
li:first-of-type + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two!</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not what i was looking for, my objective is for the image to have a grey backgournd covering with a text only when i mouse over. but whenever i mouseover any part of the col the hover effect activates

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
.hover-img:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}
```

with

```
.hover-img img:hover+.overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below style css

```
#photography:hover overlay {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

**Demo**.

```css
#photography:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.text{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nopadding{
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container App">
    <div class="caption-style-1 row">
      <div class="hover-img col-md-6 col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div id="photography">
          <img src="https://test-ipv6.com/images/hires_ok.png" class="image" title="image" >
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Photography Photography Photography</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4>CONTACT</h4>
</div>
```